# Django Channels long running consumer authentication issues

Tags: django, authentication, session, websocket, django-channels

When using django channels, I have a long-running websocket connection. My users may become logged out due to their session expiring while this connection is still active. This causes sporadic behavior where HTTP requests don't work, because they're not authenticated, but the websocket is still sending and receiving data like nothing is wrong.

The Django Channels docs say:

> If you are using a long running consumer, websocket or long-polling HTTP it is possible that the user will be logged out of their session elsewhere while your consumer is running. You can periodically use `get_user(scope)` to be sure that the user is still logged in.

However, this doesn't work. When I call the following code I'm able to see that Django Channels believes the user is still authed.

```py
user = async_to_sync(get_user)(self.scope)
print(user.is_authenticated)
```

**What is the correct way to check if a user is still authenticated in a Django Channels websocket consumer?** [This GitHub issue](https://github.com/django/channels/issues/1324) touches on the issue but doesn't have a good solution

Websocket consumer as follows:

```py
class GUIConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            GROUP_NAME, self.channel_name)

        user = self.scope.get('user')

        if user and user.has_perm('auth.can_access_ui'):
            self.accept()
        else:
            self.accept()
            self.close()

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(
            GROUP_NAME, self.channel_name)

    def data(self, event):
        publisher_type = event.get('publisher')
        data = event.get('data')
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({publisher_type: data})

    def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json.get('message', '')
        if message == "---ping---":
            self.send(text_data=json.dumps({'heartbeat': '---pong---'}))
```

Comment: You want to close websocket connection when the session expires?

Comment: @crosby, yes. When the session is expired the consumer should be able to identify that and close the connection.

Comment: What if you use something like "idle timeout"? Kinda `ping_interval/ping_timeout` in `daphne`

Comment: the problem is that processes running inside of the consumer are grabbing stale data. There should be a way to ensure we have an accurate representation of user sessions.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, I'm setting up a recurring javascript HTTP call that checks if the user is still authenticated. If the user is not authenticated I will force a page refresh which will redirect them to the login screen. This works fine, in my use case, because there's no risk of (and no reward for) my internal-only users tampering with my front end. However, this doesn't work if your code is running in a more public setting.